# Как вывести весь массив?

Tags: c, строки, циклы

Здравствуйте. 
При решении возникли трудности. Вводятся элементы "безлимитного" массива. Планируется вывести все элементы (`char`/`int`) массива, но выводит другие символы похожие на alt коды. В таблицe Ascii я не нашел ♫. Как мне решить эту проблему?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mem.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char* string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    char c;
    printf("Enter your number:\n");

    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) == '\n'; i++)
    {
        if (string == NULL)
        {
            string = (char*) malloc(i + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            string = (char*) realloc(string, i + 2);
        }

        string[i] = c;
        string[i + 1] = '\0';
    }

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        printf("a[%c]\n", string[i]);
    }

    free(string);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//a[` == 96]
//a[♫ == 14]
//a[u == 117]
```

Comment: Уже не раз тут обсуждалось, но все равно: `getchar()` возвращает `int`. Не надо хранить результат в `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените

```
(c = getchar()) == '\n'
```

на

```
(c = getchar()) != '\n'
```

Почему - объяснять?

И еще - для учебного задания `relloc` на каждый чих вызывать сойдет, но вообще-то куда разумнее при необходимости объем памяти, скажем, удваивать, отслеживая, сколько уже занято.

Comment: объясните пожалуйста, интересно.

Comment: Потому что у вас цикл был - "пока нажимаем Enter, выполнять действия", в то время как вам надо *прекратить выполнять цикл* по достижении символа новой строки...